# What is the likelihood of having none of a certain color of ball?

Tags: probability

Suppose my friend has infinitely many urns, each of which holds one marble. There are two types of marbles that can appear in an urn, red and black. My friend has decided upon some arbitrary distribution by which he can select an urn. Each urn contains a red or black marble according to some arbitrary, fixed, and unknown rule (including the possibility of having none of one color).

He poses a challenge to me: He picks an urn according to his distribution, and I guess what color the ball inside is. But before we start, he lets me name any non-negative integer $n$, and he will choose that many urns independently according to his distribution, and show me what is inside of them.

Suppose we do this procedure, and all of the marbles I see are red. I predict, therefore, for any urn that gets chosen from the same distribution, that the marble inside is red. My intuition says that if I picked a large value for $n$, I am more confident that always guessing red is a good idea. Can I place any sort of meaningful bound on how confident I am?

Comment: "Each urn contains a red or black marble according to some arbitrary, fixed, and unknown rule"  That is too ambiguous. For one thing, it's not clear if it can be a probabilistic rule, on which things could it depend, etc. Couldn't we instead assume that the ball colour is selected with a fixed probability, i.e., the colours follow an iid Bernoulli distribution with fixed unknown parameter p?

Comment: @leonbloy The color of the marble in each urn is decided before any of the urns are examined, and that decision can be based on anything at all, including but not limited to a probabilistic rule that depends on anything you want. I'm wondering if there is any interesting bound holds in all cases (given that when I do examine $n$ urns, I only see red). It is possible that the answer is simply 'no' and I am not seeing the reason why.

Comment: You cannot make any probabilistic assertion without an underlying  probabilistic model. So, the answer is 'no', as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for starters we can define $X_i$ as $1$  if the $i^{th}$ marble drawn is black and $0$  if it is red. Then $\overline{X_n}$ is an estimate of the likelihood that the marble is black (call this $p_B$). The law of large numbers states that as $n\to\infty$  we have $\overline{X_n} \to p_B$.

As for a bound, there is always Chebyshev's inequality, which for this case gives:

$$\mathbb{Pr}(|\overline{X_n}-p_B| \ge a) \le \frac{p_B(1-p_B)}{na^2}$$

Since you don't know $p_B$ we can replace it with $\overline{X_n}$ on the RHS to get an estimate for the upper bound.  Just choose an $a$ you are comfortable with first and given the law of large numbers as mentioned above, a big enough $n$ means that $\overline{X_n}$ is "close" to $p_B$ already.

Comment: I apologize, I edited the question slightly as you were writing this answer. It looks like Chebyshev's inequality may still apply, though?

Comment: As far as I can tell the problem is the same with your new wording. As long as your prior statement that all mixtures of red/black is still true.